# Looking for a class to create and parse configuration files in various formats in c#

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, mono

I want to use (read/write/change) configuration files which have various formats. Life for instance

```
key1: value1
key2: value2
```

or

```
[section1]
key=value

[section2]
key=value
```

I assume that there are a million different classes flying around the web, which accomplish this not very extraordinary task, but I was unable to find a good implementation. Could someone reccomend one?

Comment: You could look here for some ideas. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/readwritexmlini.aspx Possibly you could use it off the bat or with minor tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old, but generally works: [Nini](http://nini.sourceforge.net/). About the supported formats: look [here](http://nini.sourceforge.net/Manual/NiniManual-4.htm).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I'm not sure if it suites my needs. The documentation doesn't help with some details (like comment handling, preserving the order within a file)